# How do I make a variable accessible from another python script when accessed from modulename.main() method

Tags: python

I have a simple python script which invokes the main function of another python script. Something like this:

`invoker_code.py`:

```
import os
invoked_code = '/tmp/invoked_code.py'
import sys
if os.path.exists(invoked_code):
    sys.append(invoked_code)
else:
    sys.exit(1)
import invoked_code
__data_bag = { 'var' : 'value' }
invoked_code.main()
```

`/tmp/invoked_code.py`:

```
def main():
    print '%s' %(__data_bag['var'])
```

I want the `invoked_code` to be able to access the variable `__dict_bag` from within its code base. This should be achieved with minimal or zero code changes on the `invoked_code.py` script as this is a third party script and I do not have write access to this script. How can I do that?

Comment: where does `invoked_code.py` get `__data_bag` from if is ran directly?

Comment: Just pass `__data_bag` to `invoked_code.main`: `invoked_code.main(__data_bag)`.

Comment: @zhangxaochen the invoked_code.py would get it from a test data  properties file which may not exists at deployment time.

Comment: @solusipse That's the easiest and I might have to revert back to that. However I was hoping for a bit cleaner solution wherein I wouldn't need to change the invoked_code.py at all

Comment: @JourneyMan You have it backwards: The *clean solution* would be having the function in the invoked code accept the data it wants to work with as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modules can access and modify each other's global variables:

**module1.py**:

```
foobar = [1, 2, 3]
def main():
    print foobar[0]
def printx():
    print x
```

**module2.py**:

```
import module1
print module1.foobar
module1.main()
module1.foobar[0] = 100
module1.main()
module1.x = "exex"
module1.printx()
```

Running `module2.py`:

```
[1, 2, 3]
1
100
exex
```

Note that you can both modify a global variable in the other module, and also create one. However, I would instead recommend doing as poke said and passing the variable into the invoked function.

Comment: Can you explain as to why the suggested solution by poke is better.

Comment: @JourneyMan Claudiu is referring to editing `main` in `invoked_code` to accept the data as a parameter.

Comment: The thing is the `invoked_code` is never touched by me. This is a job orchestration framework and I will never have access to the python script that get's executed. Hence I wanted to keep minimal code changes on the `invoked_code` side.

Comment: If that code is a completely separate entity, then it’s even more odd that it is using some module-global variable without offering a way to modify that. And modifying such a variable from the outside is definitely worrying as that could cause side effects you are not aware of—especially when you don’t have control over that code (a variable starting with two underscores usually means private and internal, so you really shouldn’t edit it).

Answer (score 0):

The `main` function in `invoked_code` will look up the `__data_bag` name within its own scope. So it will first try to find it inside of the function itself and then go up to module level, i.e. what’s defined in the `invoked_code.py`.

As `__data_bag` does not exist in either places, the function won’t be able to find it. So to solve this without changing the `invoked_code`, you need to supply the data to a place where the function will look at. The only place you have access to is the module though, so that’s the only thing you can do:

```
import invoked_code
invoked_code.__data_bag = { 'var' : 'value' }
invoked_code.main()
```

Note that this is really not a good way to solve this problem though. The proper way to solve this would be to have the `main` function accept a parameter for this:

```
def main(data_bag):
    print '%s' %(data_bag['var'])
```

Then you could simply pass the value in your invoking script:

```
invoked_code.main(__data_bag)
```

Comment: It is possible - see my answer. But yes the correct solution would be to pass it into the function if possible